# Cassandra cluster still trying to reach old IP

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

I've seen a strange behaviour since a node decommission; regularly some Cassandra nodes start massively outputting these logs:

```
OutboundTcpConnection.java:570 - Cannot handshake version with /10.208.58.4
```

The issue is that that IP matches a non Cassandra pod. It's like that IP is a leftover of an old pod, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this issue isn't uncommon in a Kubernetes paradigm. The cluster will "remember" the IPs of old nodes for up to 72 hours after they've been removed or decommissioned...and sometimes just won't "forget" about them for longer than that. You can get rid of it by running:

```
nodetool assassinate 10.208.58.4
```